# Single header row for child gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a nested gridview that is working wonderfully with one seemingly simple problem. I don't want the headers repeated on each child gridview. I would like the headers for the child gridview to be displayed in the parent gridview's  TemplateField HeaderText area. I cannot seem to find a good way to do this.

For Instance, I currently have this....

```
 gv1Header 

           gv2Header gv2Header

 data         data     data
              data     data

           gv2Header gv2Header
 data         data     data     
              data     data
```

But I would like to see this...

```
gv1Header    gv2Header   gv2Header
   data         data        data 
                data        data
   data         data        data
                data        data
```

Any ideas? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Implement GridView's event RowDataBound and keep the value for each cell in column of gv1Header.  If the value in the cell is the same as the previous value, then set the cell text to empty string.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is use multiple inner gridview for each columns and set

> ShowHeader="false"

For example if your inner grid have 3 column you should add 3 templatefield in main grid.

```
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grd" AutoGenerateColumns="false">

        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="col1" DataField="name" />

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Col2" >
                <ItemTemplate>

                   <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="fdf" ShowHeader="false">
                       <Columns>
                           <asp:BoundField DataField="InnerCol1" />
                       </Columns>
                   </asp:GridView>

                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>


            <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Col3" >
                <ItemTemplate>

                   <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="fdf" ShowHeader="false">
                       <Columns>
                           <asp:BoundField DataField="InnerCol2" />
                       </Columns>
                   </asp:GridView>

                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>



        </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>
```